# Is there a way to delete filtered rows from jquery datatable (jquerydatatable 1.9)?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here is my code:

```
var companyTable =$('#companyTable').dataTable();
var filteredRows = companyTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"})
filteredRows.forEach(function(item) {
    $('#companyTable').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(item);
});
```

It is deleted all the rows but last one is left and its showing error like    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTr' of undefined, could some one help me on this.

Comment: Can you show us an example with your problem? Oh and try `$('#companyTable').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(item[0]);`

Comment: My task is to remove the filtered rows on a button click (Remove All) on click of the button i have added the above code. I tried $('#companyTable').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(item[0]) aswell but the result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution for question.

```
        var companyTable =$('#companyTable').dataTable();

       //get all nodes of the datatable it returns all rows
        var allNodes = companyTable.fnGetNodes();

       //get filtered rows of datatable            
         var filteredRows = companyTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});
        var filteredArray= [];
        for(var i=0;i<filteredRows.length;i++) {
            var item = filteredRows[i];
            //am using some column to compare both 
            var column= item[1];
            filteredArray.push(column);
        }

        for (var i=0;i<allNodes.length;i++){
            var rowData = allNodes[i];
            var columnData= $(rowData).find('td:eq(0)').text();

            //if the node is in filtered data remove it..
            if(jQuery.inArray( columnData, filteredArray) != -1 ){

              //here i am removing the row
                var rowData = companyTable.fnDeleteRow(rowData);
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an easier solution.
When selecting your rows, use `{ filter : 'applied'}`.

So in your case it would be:

```
companyTable.rows({ filter : 'applied'}).remove().draw();
```